# My discord.py bot is only loading one cog from my cogs folder and I need it load all of them

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I run my bot it is only loading one cog from my cogs folder when I need it to load all of them. If anyone could help me with this issue it would be greatly appreciated I will attach my code below.

This is my main.py file.

```
import asyncio
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

async def loadext():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")


async def main():
    await loadext()
    await bot.start("TOKEN")


asyncio.run(main())
```

This is my ping.py file which is the only cog that my bot is loading.

```
from discord.ext import commands


class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(self.bot.latency * 1000)}ms!")
        print(f"Bot latency is {round(self.bot.latency * 1000)}ms!")


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

and finally this is my cog that I need loaded but it isn't loading.

````
import discord
from stuff import *
from discord.ext import commands


class IGBan(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        user = message.author
        guild = message.guild
        channel = message.channel
        content = message.content
        user1 = await self.bot.fetch_user("1123271715984769044")
        user2 = await self.bot.fetch_user("847981083625914389")

        if content.startswith("!1"):
            reason = reason1

            if ":" in content:
                parts = content.split(":")
                username = parts[1]
                name = parts[2]
                email = parts[3]
                print(
                    f"Mode: {reason} \n Username: {username} \n Name: {name} \n Email: {email}"
                )
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"⚡ Unban Mode: {reason}", color=0x8A3AB9)
                embed.set_author(name="Unban Request Sent Successfully!")
                embed.add_field(name="Username", value=f"{username}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=f"{name}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Email", value=f"{email}", inline=False)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await user1.send(embed=embed)
                await user2.send(embed=embed)

        elif content.startswith("!2"):
            reason = reason2
            if ":" in content:
                parts = content.split(":")
                username = parts[1]
                name = parts[2]
                email = parts[3]
                print(
                    f"Mode: {reason} \n Username: {username} \n Name: {name} \n Email: {email}"
                )
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"⚡ Unban Mode: {reason}", color=0x8A3AB9)
                embed.set_author(name="Unban Request Sent Successfully!")
                embed.add_field(name="Username", value=f"{username}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=f"{name}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Email", value=f"{email}", inline=False)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await user1.send(embed=embed)
                await user2.send(embed=embed)

        elif content.startswith("!3"):
            reason = reason3

            if ":" in content:
                parts = content.split(":")
                username = parts[1]
                name = parts[2]
                email = parts[3]
                print(
                    f"Mode: {reason} \n Username: {username} \n Name: {name} \n Email: {email}"
                )
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"⚡ Unban Mode: {reason}", color=0x8A3AB9)
                embed.set_author(name="Unban Request Sent Successfully!")
                embed.add_field(name="Username", value=f"{username}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=f"{name}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Email", value=f"{email}", inline=False)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await user1.send(embed=embed)
                await user2.send(embed=embed)

        elif content.startswith("!4"):
            reason = reason4

            if ":" in content:
                parts = content.split(":")
                username = parts[1]
                name = parts[2]
                email = parts[3]
                print(
                    f"Mode: {reason} \n Username: {username} \n Name: {name} \n Email: {email}"
                )
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"⚡ Unban Mode: {reason}", color=0x8A3AB9)
                embed.set_author(name="Unban Request Sent Successfully!")
                embed.add_field(name="Username", value=f"{username}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=f"{name}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Email", value=f"{email}", inline=False)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await user1.send(embed=embed)
                await user2.send(embed=embed)

        elif content.startswith("!5"):
            reason = reason5

            if ":" in content:
                parts = content.split(":")
                username = parts[1]
                name = parts[2]
                email = parts[3]
                print(
                    f"Mode: {reason} \n Username: {username} \n Name: {name} \n Email: {email}"
                )
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"⚡ Unban Mode: {reason}", color=0x8A3AB9)
                embed.set_author(name="Unban Request Sent Successfully!")
                embed.add_field(name="Username", value=f"{username}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=f"{name}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Email", value=f"{email}", inline=False)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await user1.send(embed=embed)
                await user2.send(embed=embed)

        elif content.startswith("!6"):
            reason = reason6

            if ":" in content:
                parts = content.split(":")
                username = parts[1]
                name = parts[2]
                email = parts[3]
                print(
                    f"Mode: {reason} \n Username: {username} \n Name: {name} \n Email: {email}"
                )
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"⚡ Unban Mode: {reason}", color=0x8A3AB9)
                embed.set_author(name="Unban Request Sent Successfully!")
                embed.add_field(name="Username", value=f"{username}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=f"{name}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Email", value=f"{email}", inline=False)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await user1.send(embed=embed)
                await user2.send(embed=embed)

        elif content.startswith("!7"):
            reason = reason7

            if ":" in content:
                parts = content.split(":")
                username = parts[1]
                name = parts[2]
                email = parts[3]
                print(
                    f"Mode: {reason} \n Username: {username} \n Name: {name} \n Email: {email}"
                )
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"⚡ Unban Mode: {reason}", color=0x8A3AB9)
                embed.set_author(name="Unban Request Sent Successfully!")
                embed.add_field(name="Username", value=f"{username}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=f"{name}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Email", value=f"{email}", inline=False)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await user1.send(embed=embed)
                await user2.send(embed=embed)



    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_role('Blue')
    async def igunban(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Use for Following Reasons:", color=0x8A3AB9)
        embed.set_author(name="IG Unbanner")
        embed.add_field(name=f"[1] {reason1}", value="", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=f"[2] {reason2}", value="", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=f"[3] {reason3}", value="", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=f"[4] {reason4}", value="", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=f"[5] {reason5}", value="", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=f"[6] {reason6}", value="", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name=f"[7] {reason7}", value="", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="** **", value="```Usage```", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(
            name="", value="```!reason:username:name:email```", inline=False
        )
        embed.add_field(name="** **", value="```Example```", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(
            name="", value="```!7:John_doe:JohnDoe:JohnDoe@example.com```", inline=False
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(IGBan(bot))
````

It loads the @commands.Cog.listener() part and executes what it is supposed to when it sees a message but the commands don't work and it doesn't show up in the default discord help command

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: maybe use `print()` to check `filename` and `filename.endswith(".py")` - maybe your files don't have extension `.py`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself from playing around with the code.

my code had `@commands.has_role('Blue')` in it and I was executing the command without actually having the role myself which led to the command not showing up because I didn't have the role.